# Video.js not supporting flash in firefox on osx

Tags: macos, flash, firefox, mp4, video.js

I am currently working on a site which needs to contain a videoplayer, but they only have MP4 videos. Considering Firefox doesn't support MP4, I need native (where possible) and flash support.

I force fallback to flash in Firefox using this piece of code:

```
if (_V_.isFF()) {
    _V_.options.techOrder = ["flash"];
}
```

This does happen, and if I set the above through the console in chrome I do get a flash fallback. Thing is, when I use Firefox I don't see any object tag, just a black square (and a video-tag in the source). Even on videojs.com itself there is no object tag but a video-tag?! (edit; clarification: i do click on the "flash"-button there.)

I'm a bit puzzled by this. Anyone else experiencing this/know what may be the cause?

Comment: Fallback to Flash should happen by default on Firefox if the only source is MP4 You shouldn't even need to make that switch. I'd suspect something's up with the Flash install on that particular machine. Have you updated Flash recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering there are dozens of videos, using webm (sadly) isn't an option. Also, videojs wasn't found to be fluid on android devices. Because of this, we've decided to just link to the video (with a poster image) and play the video natively on androids.

Answer (score 0):

The mp4 file must be converted to a webm and both files used in the videojs player, period.

In the great media wars flash has been eliminated from androids, thats why the webm file is a key component in videojs.The mp4 file must be converted into a webm file and both sources used. You can just upload the webm vid to fileserver as well and link both sources in the player. The filenames in the link to the server must end in .mp4 and .webm to be recognized.

2 must reads -
http://www.zdnet.com/androids-flash-player-is-dead-live-with-it-7000002668/

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3417930/how-get-flash-in-android-jelly-bean/

The quickest way to convert a mp4 to webm without software is to upload it to youtube, once the video is there copy the link and go to keepvid.com, then download the webm. Remember the highest quality webm file is not always optimal do to the size of mobile devices and slow internet connections planetwide. The video quality toggle on videojs is on the way though.